# Greedy Algorithm - maximum acyclic edge-set

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

How do I prove that the following algorithm does indeed produce a maximum acyclic edge set.

```
Greedy Algorithm:
F := ∅
For Each Edge e ∈ E:
If F ∪ {e} is Acyclic:
F := F ∪ {e}
Return F
```

My initial thoughts were to use induction, but not sure how to proceed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Prove for a connected component, that this algorithm finds a spanning tree for that component and that corresponds to maximal set of acyclic edges (adding any more than #vertices in the comp - 1 edges will form a cycle).